# Make pytorch reserve certain amount of GPU memory upfront

Tags: python, pytorch, shared-gpu-memory

My code has two workflows that run sequentially. In the first workflow, it requires only about 8GB of GPU memory, but the second workflow takes about 22GB. Is it possible to reserve 22GB upfront (even while running the first workflow) even if it is not using all the memory at that time?

I run my code on a shared machine. When my code is in the first workflow, if someone runs another program in parallel on the same card using the remaining memory, my code crashes when it reaches the second workflow. That's why I want to reserve the required memory upfront.